# J5. Access editor instances in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, editor, joomla-5.x

In JavaScript and J4, to get an editor object from the collection of objects with all editor instances running I use:

```
let editor = Joomla.editors.instances[myEditorName];
```

I can see Joomla object in my console with all properties, editors.instances included.

Now in J5 it's deprecated and editors.instances is empty. I have read some information about the reasons to replace this code with JoomlaEditor, but this does not appear in my console. Please, how can I access to the editors instances or editors objects in JavaScript / Joomla 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Editor API is now an ESM, so you will need to import it in your Javascript file.

```
import { JoomlaEditor } from 'editor-api';

const editor = JoomlaEditor.get(id); // Replace "id" with ID of your editor element
console.log(editor);
```

You'll also need to ensure that your own Javascript file is set to be included as a module:

```
{
    "name": "foobar",
    "type": "script",
    "uri": "your_file.js",
    "attributes": {
        "type": "module"
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

@Lodder, thanks but maybe I have doing something wrong because browser console shows:

```
EDITOR:  false
```

This is my reduced configuration:

```
//** /media/com_abaco/js/editor.js

import { JoomlaEditor } from 'editor-api';
const editor = JoomlaEditor.get('myEditorId'); 
console.log('EDITOR: ', editor); 

//** /media/com_abaco/joomla.asset.json
...
    "assets": [
    {
        "name": "com_abaco.editor",
        "type": "script",
        "uri": "com_abaco/editor.js",
        "dependencies": [
            "codemirror"
        ],
        "attributes": {
            "type": "module",
            "defer": true
        }
    }

//** /components/com_abaco/src/View/Editor/HtmlView.php
...
$this->editor = Editor::getInstance('codemirror');
$wa = $this->document->getWebAssetManager();
$wa->useScript('com_abaco.editor');

//** /components/com_abaco/tmpl/editor/default.php

<?= $this->editor->display('myEditorId', 'My custom content', '100%', '900', '300', '3', false, 'myEditorId', null, null, array()); ?>
```

Codemirror editor is showing as expected but I can't access it in JavaScript. My file `editor.js` is loaded before `editors.js`, `joomla-editor-codemirror.js` and `codemirror.js`.  I don't know if this it's important.

Comment: A delay after Import to load editor-api and it works. I can't understand why not use Web Assets Manager to load editor-api and in other file create the editor object as dependency.